# Why am I getting an invalid syntax error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, terminal, pip

I am following a tutorial on installing the Requests library, a HTTP library for Python.   [Requests Installation Guide](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/#install)

The tutorial says to install the Requests library, simply run this command in my terminal

```
pip install requests
```

I didn't which terminal to run this command in but I first tried Windows cmd after downloading pip, the package management system used to install and manage software packages written in Python(shown below)
[image]

I then tried the Python 3.4.2 terminal(shown below)

[image]

Does anyone know which terminal to run this command in and what my syntax error is for that terminal(tried both)? To me it's weird because the Python terminal was able to recognize pip but not install.....

Comment: You should include the location of `pip` in the `PATH` variable and then try to install from the command prompt

Comment: Thank you! Just by curiosity, when i pip install request in the command prompt, how does the operating system know to which pip to call? In that scripts directory, I have pip, pip3.4, and pip3....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also create a virtual environment for your project and install all the modules you would like to use. It looks like you are using a windows machine. The commands would be as follows

```
C:dirrectory_for_your_project>c:\Python34\python.exe c:\Python34\Tools\Scripts\pyvenv.py env  #create your environment
C:dirrectory_for_your_project>env\Scripts\activate.bat   #activate your enviornment
(env) C:dirrectory_for_your_project>pip install requests #pip modules you would like to include in your project
(env) C:dirrectory_for_your_project>python script.py     #run script
```

There is also a deactivate script for when you would like to exit the env. Make sure to activate the env whenever you are trying to run the script from the command line and all should be fine.

Note: This is just another solution to your problem and is based on personal preference. You should still add the necessary scripts to your path as this might come in handy in the future.

Comment: Where did you get c:\Python34\Tools\Scripts\pyvenv.py  from? I don't have pyvenv.py(Python extension) in my Scripts directory.

Comment: You should see it when you look in the directory. It comes with py 3.4. Make sure you are looking in the right directory. There is a scripts folder directly in python34 with scripts such as easy_install.py and pip.py. That is not the directory you should be in. You need to look in tools then scripts. If you still don't see it, just upgrade your python version to the latest python 3.4.3 (as it may have been a recent add that did not exist in the version of python you are using). Oh and something else I forgot to mention. You can run win_add2path.py to configure python in your path variables

Comment: When you write out the command, do you actually put the env in parenthesis?

Answer (score 4):

You are running the `pip install` from your [python](/questions/tagged/python) shell. Exit from the [python](/questions/tagged/python) shell and run it from your [bash](/questions/tagged/bash).

Comment: Thank you! I did run it from my Windows shell program - CMD. Issue was I needed to add it to my Path environmental variable. Is bash just cmd by the way?

Comment: @committedandroider yep :)

Answer (score 2):

pip.exe will be in the `C:\Python34\Scripts` folder. You can add that folder to your PATH environment variable if you want to run pip from anywhere, or you can just CD into the Scripts folder from where you are and run it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing anything with `PATH` I suggest you use `pip` on command line with `python -mpip`, as in `python -mpip install somepackage`.